# Annoying php error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have spent the last 6 hours searching the web and looking over my code but yet I continue to get this error message.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$register' at line 1

here is my code (well the part that I believe the problem lies with):

```
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$title = $_POST['titlename'];
$author = $_POST['author'];

$register = mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (month, day, author, content, title) VALUES ('$month', '$day', '$author', '$content', '$title')");
    mysql_query('$register');
    echo mysql_error();
```

I have a table called "posts", the spelling is correct on everything, and all the quotes have mates. I am completely stumped. The really weird part is, I have compared it to previous code of mine that actually works and there really is no difference.

PS I do realize that I shouldn't use user inputs directly into the table, however I am going to be the only one accessing this table. I am making this table to make my life easier.

Comment: apart from the quotes.. you are running mysql_query on the result of mysql_query

Comment: This has worked for me in the past

Comment: 2 words: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 5):

Remove quotes..

```
 mysql_query($register);
```

---

**Update**

You are running you sql query twice. Remove `mysql_query('$register');`

Comment: 6 Hours <=> 1 Minute.. ;)

Comment: and the fact that he is running mysql_query twice.. once on a string and once on a resource/boolean value..

Comment: :) I was in a hurry also anyway.. he was running it on the string '$register', not on the result.. since those are single quotes.. hence the error message he posted :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$title = $_POST['titlename'];
$author = $_POST['author'];

$register = "INSERT INTO posts (month, day, author, content, title) VALUES ('$month', '$day', '$author', '$content', '$title')";
    mysql_query($register);
    echo mysql_error();
```

You better do some mysql_real_escape_string() before the query like:

```
 $author = mysql_real_escape_string($author);
```

to avoid SQL injection or failure if the sting contains single quote inside

Answer (score -1):

Also , mysql_query is somehome not good , maybe unsupported in the future. Please use mysqli_query instead

```
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO posts (month, day, author, content, title) VALUES ('$month', '$day', '$author', '$content', '$title')");
```

instead.

And remove the

```
    mysql_query('$register');
```

Cheers

Comment: Why vote down? **REASON** please , i am a man of science.